# How can I allow anonymous users to see the file for the exported webform submission data?

Tags: webforms, 9

On Drupal 9.2.1, I have a data export set up for webform submission fields in a XML file which is imported by another site.

When I am logged-in, I can view the .xml without issues. Since the permission to view webform submissions is only given to administrator users, the anonymous users see an empty page.

How can I allow anonymous users to see the file for the exported webform submission data?

Answer (score 0):

For using submission data in a view is controlled by the "View submission data" permissions for the webform.  Exposing the data opens the results page to the anonymous user which is not desired.

A solution that I found is the Webform Content Creator module.  This will allow you to map webform submission data to a content type so it can be used in a view or xml file.

Its not the perfect solution but is a solution if anyone else is having this issue.